# sprintf_s(and sprintf also) has error in Windows 7 64 bits with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c, x86-64, windows-7-x64, printf

I am programming in Windows 7 64 bits with VS 2013.
I already have a code which was developed in Linux 64 bits. That code is full of sprintf() functions.

Now, I run that code in Windows 64 bits, it shows alert windows.
At first, I tried sprintf, and it shows use sprintf_s. So I changed.

After change my code window shows this error.

```
Program : ...visual studio
2012\Project\IIS_Partial\Debug\IIS_Partial.exe
File : f\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\vsprintf.c
Line : 233

Expression : format != NULL

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press retry to debug the application)
```

Actually my code is made in C. Why this refers C++.
And I could even debug, because pressing the "debug" button directly goes to this error window. Are there any clues?

Thanks for reading:D

Comment: `Assert evaluates an expression and, when the result is false, prints a diagnostic message and aborts the program` - Microsoft.

Looks like the `format` is `NULL` in some line.

Comment: If you blanket-changed `sprintf()` with `sprintf_s()` you're not done yet. I suggest you read the documentation on the differences, and specifically the only cases where they *are* swap-replacable, namely those where a fixed array is the buffer target. And even that isn't the case if you're compiling straight C, as it is provided via a C++ template.

Comment: If you just wanted to shut up the warnings about `sprintf` you can add `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before you include `<stdio.h>`. Also note that Visual Studio is a `C++` compiler and doesn't support some `C` features.

Comment: Thanks for all of you. However, my problem has solved in different way. It was just basic setting of Visual Studio 2012. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a simple configuration matter.
Basically Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 is compiling as 32 bits.

So if someone want to run a source code in 64 bits, has to change options.

right click on [solution] -> [properties] -> [Configuration] -> [Configuration Manager](right upper corner of window) -> [Active Solution Platform] flow Menu ->  -> upper is 'x64' and lower is 'Win32'. check the lower box.

and confirm. Now it builds in 64 bits environment.
Original Explanation from Microsoft Official site is :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9yb4317s.aspx